# node view Unpublished is not working

Tags: users

I just add a Node `view_unpublished` module for providing access to view unpulished node . After instalation i set the Permission `View any unpublished content` and `MyType: View any unpublished content` . 
After doing this there is no change in access .Role still didn't access the node.

Any suggestion will be most appreciable.

thanks in advance ...:)

Comment: Standard question: Did you clear all caches and did you rebuilt permissions?

Comment: Do you have any other content access modules activated? Can your role edit an unpublished node?

Comment: no i don't want to give the edit permission to that role .

Comment: have you tried turning off all custom modules to check you haven't got an override of roles somewhere.

Comment: i don't have any custom module installed